# 別々のインスタンスなのにリストの値が共有されるのはどうして

Tags: python, python3

Pythonで下記のコードを書いたのですが、思っていたのとは違う動作をします。なぜなのでしょうか？

```
class Shape():
    pass
    
class Square(Shape):
    squs = []
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.squs.append((self.width, self.height))

square = Square(40, 40)
square1 = Square(50, 50)

print(square1.squs)
#結果[(40, 40), (50, 50)]空のリストを代入してから、appendしているので消えそうな気もするのですが？？
```

追記

```
class Shape():
    pass
    
class Square(Shape):
    squs = []
    n = 1
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.squs.append((self.width, self.height))
        self.n = n + 100

square = Square(40, 40)
square1 = Square(50, 50)
print(square1.n)
print(square.n)
```

nが定義されていないというメッセージが出てくるのですが、混乱してきました。
予想では101、201と出力されると思いました。

詳しい方ご回答いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class文が何をするか? という話ですね。

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions

> 次にクラスのスイートが、新たな実行フレーム (名前づけと束縛 (naming and binding) を参照してください) 内で、新たに作られたローカル名前空間と元々のグローバル名前空間を使って実行されます (通常、このスイートには主に関数定義が含まれます)。クラスのスイートが実行し終えると、実行フレームは破棄されますが、ローカルな名前空間は保存されます。次に、継承リストを基底クラスに、保存されたローカル名前空間を属性値辞書に、それぞれ使ってクラスオブジェクトが生成されます。最後に、もとのローカル名前空間において、クラス名がこのクラスオブジェクトに束縛されます。

1. クラスのスイート(本体)が、新たな実行フレーム内で、新たに作られたローカル名前空間と元々のグローバル名前空間を使って実行される
2. 実行フレームが破棄される
3. ただしローカルな名前空間が保存される
4. 継承リストを基底クラスに、保存されたローカル名前空間を属性値辞書に、それぞれ使ってクラスオブジェクトが生成される
5. もとのローカル名前空間において、クラス名がこのクラスオブジェクトに束縛される

これだけのことが起こります。

---

ところで関数定義文は実行した時に[関数本体を実行しません](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)。
関数の本体は、"def文が実行された時"には**実行されず**、"関数が呼び出された時"に初めて実行されます。

対してclass文の本体は、"class文が実行された時"に一度だけ**実行され**、以降は**実行されることはありません**。

質問者さんが誤解している、あるいは理解してないことはこの点かと思います。

---

(若干余談)

```py
class Hoge:
    print('body')
    def __init__(self):
        print('init')
print('top level')
Hoge()
```

の実行結果を、実行せずに予測できますか?

Comment: 関数は最初のみ実行（読み込み）されているこれがクラス文に対しても行われていて、initのみインスタンス生成時に実行されると言うことですね。

Comment: "initのみインスタンス生成時に"
この「のみ」の意図がわかりませんでした、というのとインスタンス生成「直後」が正確かなというのはりますが、おおむねその通りかと。

Comment: initは実行されて他のメソッド、クラス変数は読み込まれるのみみたいな表現で使用したかったのでそのように書きました。どちらも実行されていると言えばそうなんですけどinitは動作してる、メソッド、クラス変数は読み込みに留まる？難しいですね表現が...

Comment: 「def文の実行」と「def文で出来た関数オブジェクトの実行」を区別するのが難しいのと似ていますね。「def文が実行された時には本体が実行されていない」「class文が実行された時には本体が実行されている」も難しい……

Answer (score 1):

前半について：

質問者さんに共有頂いたコードにおいて、`squs = []` は `Square` クラスを定義した際に一度だけ実行されます。その後、`Square` をインスタンス化した際に実行されるのは `__init__` であり、`squs = []` は実行されません。

これらのことは、次のコードを実行することで確かめられます。

```py
class Square:
    squs = []
    print('Square defined')

    def __init__(self, w, h):
        print('__init__ called')
        self.squs.append((w, h))

print('squs:', Square.squs)
Square(1, 1)
print('squs:', Square.squs)
Square(2, 2)
print('squs:', Square.squs)

# Square defined
# squs: []
# __init__ called
# squs: [(1, 1)]
# __init__ called
# squs: [(1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

---

追記について：

変数 `n` は `__init__` のスコープにありません。`self.n` で呼び出す必要があります。

```py
class Square:
    n = 1
    squs = []
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.squs.append((w, h))
        self.n = self.n + 100
                                                                                         
print('Square.n', Square.n)
print('Square.squs', Square.squs)
                                                                        
square1 = Square(1, 1)
print('Square.n', Square.n)
print('Square.squs', Square.squs)
print('square1.n', square1.n)
print('square1.squs', square1.squs)

# Square.n 1
# Square.squs []
# Square.n 1
# Square.squs [(1, 1)]
# square1.n 101
# square1.squs [(1, 1)]
```

ここでもう一つ混乱しうる点は、`squs` はリスト型でミュータブルなのでインスタンス間で共有される一方、`n` は整数型でイミュータブルなのでインスタンス間で共有されないことです。

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

変数 `squs` がインスタンス間で共有されないようにするには、クラス変数ではなくインスタンス変数として導入します。

```py
class Square:
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.squs = []
        self.squs.append((w, h))
```

クラス変数 `n` を `__init__` で書き換えたい場合は次のようにします。

```py
class Square:
    n = 1
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.__class__.n += 100
```

Answer (score 0):

そのコードで言うところの `squs` (`Square.squs`) はインスタンス変数ではなくクラス変数です。

Python ドキュメント [9.3.5. クラスとインスタンス変数](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) を参照してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。グローバル変数の様なものですね。そのクラス全てのインスタンスで共有されるのですね。でも不思議です。別のインスタンスを作成するときにもう一度`squs = []`が実行されて空になりそうです。

Comment: リスト・辞書の場合だけこのような動作になるのですね。なぜこのような仕様にしたのか不思議です。